# Закрыть меню кликом на свободную область этого же меню

Tags: javascript, jquery

Есть такое меню:

```js
$('.trigger').on('click', function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();

  var $this = $(this),
    trigger = $('.trigger'),
    nav = $('nav');

  if (!$this.hasClass('on')) {
    trigger.addClass('on');
    nav.addClass('show');
    $('body').addClass('open');
  } else {
    trigger.removeClass('on');
    nav.removeClass('show');
    $('body').removeClass('open');
  }


});
```

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

html,
body {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

main {
  height: 100%;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  padding: 2rem;
  font-size: 1.5rem;
  line-height: 2.5rem;
  background: #000;
  color: #fff;
  padding-top: 70px;
}

header {
  background: #fff;
  height: 50px;
  text-align: right;
}

.trigger {
  color: #000;
  font-size: 2rem;
}

nav .trigger {
  color: #fff;
}

nav {
  height: 100%;
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 100;
  right: 0;
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: flex-end;
  background: rgba(255, 255, 255, .75);
  transition: transform .3s;
  transform: translateX(100%);
}

nav.show {
  transform: translateX(0%);
}

.nav-inner {
  width: 50%;
  background: blue;
  height: 100%;
}

.open main {
  filter: blur(10px);
}

nav ul {
  margin-top: 50px;
}

nav ul li {
  margin: 20px 0;
}

nav ul a {
  color: #fff;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.4.js"></script>

<nav>
  <div class="nav-inner">
    <a href="" class="trigger">
          close menu
        </a>

    <ul>
      <li>
        <a href="https://ru.stackoverflow.com/" target="_blank">ссылка</a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="https://ru.stackoverflow.com/" target="_blank">ссылка</a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="https://ru.stackoverflow.com/" target="_blank">ссылка</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</nav>

<header>
  <a href="" class="trigger">
      open menu
    </a>
</header>

<main>
  <p>
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Animi voluptatem autem, velit totam, minima quibusdam ea ipsa in saepe eos corporis ipsam dicta, quisquam amet nihil dolores ab officiis ut officia alias accusamus voluptas asperiores dignissimos
    iste ipsum. Nam fugit officia, obcaecati! Quia hic, quasi, modi sequi esse odio deserunt!
  </p>
</main>
```

**ВАЖНО:** меню такое как есть на всю ширину экрана, т.е. свободную область нельзя псевдоэлементом сделать или как-то менять `html`!

**Вопрос:** Как закрыть его при клике на свободную область все этого же меню?

При этом внутри `nav` ссылки должны быть кликабельны и ничего не нарушается.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```js
let $nav = $('nav'),
    $navInner = $('.nav-inner'),
    $navTrigger = $nav.add($navInner);
$navTrigger.on('click', function(event) {
  if ($(event.target).is($navTrigger)) {
    $nav.removeClass('show');
  }
})

$('.trigger').on('click', function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();

  var $this = $(this),
    trigger = $('.trigger'),
    nav = $('nav');

  if (!$this.hasClass('on')) {
    trigger.addClass('on');
    nav.addClass('show');
    $('body').addClass('open');
  } else {
    trigger.removeClass('on');
    nav.removeClass('show');
    $('body').removeClass('open');
  }


});
```

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

html,
body {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

main {
  height: 100%;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  padding: 2rem;
  font-size: 1.5rem;
  line-height: 2.5rem;
  background: #000;
  color: #fff;
  padding-top: 70px;
}

header {
  background: #fff;
  height: 50px;
  text-align: right;
}

.trigger {
  color: #000;
  font-size: 2rem;
}

nav .trigger {
  color: #fff;
}

nav {
  height: 100%;
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 100;
  right: 0;
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: flex-end;
  background: rgba(255, 255, 255, .75);
  transition: transform .3s;
  transform: translateX(100%);
}

nav.show {
  transform: translateX(0%);
}

.nav-inner {
  width: 50%;
  background: blue;
  height: 100%;
}

.open main {
  filter: blur(10px);
}

nav ul {
  margin-top: 50px;
}

nav ul li {
  margin: 20px 0;
}

nav ul a {
  color: #fff;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.4.js"></script>

<nav>
  <div class="nav-inner">
    <a href="" class="trigger">
          close menu
        </a>

    <ul>
      <li>
        <a href="https://ru.stackoverflow.com/" target="_blank">ссылка</a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="https://ru.stackoverflow.com/" target="_blank">ссылка</a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="https://ru.stackoverflow.com/" target="_blank">ссылка</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</nav>

<header>
  <a href="" class="trigger">
      open menu
    </a>
</header>

<main>
  <p>
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Animi voluptatem autem, velit totam, minima quibusdam ea ipsa in saepe eos corporis ipsam dicta, quisquam amet nihil dolores ab officiis ut officia alias accusamus voluptas asperiores dignissimos
    iste ipsum. Nam fugit officia, obcaecati! Quia hic, quasi, modi sequi esse odio deserunt!
  </p>
</main>
```

Answer (score 2):

```js
$('.trigger').on('click', function(e) {
  
  e.preventDefault();
  var $this = $(this),
    trigger = $('.trigger'),
    nav = $('nav');
  if (!$this.hasClass('on')) {
    trigger.addClass('on');
    nav.addClass('show');
    $('body').addClass('open');
  } else {
    trigger.removeClass('on');
    nav.removeClass('show');
    $('body').removeClass('open');
  }
});

$('nav').on('click', function(e){
  if(e.target.tagName !== 'A'){
    $(this).removeClass('show');
    $('body').removeClass('open');
    $('.trigger').removeClass('on');    
  }
})
```

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

html,
body {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

main {
  height: 100%;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  padding: 2rem;
  font-size: 1.5rem;
  line-height: 2.5rem;
  background: #000;
  color: #fff;
  padding-top: 70px;
}

header {
  background: #fff;
  height: 50px;
  text-align: right;
}

.trigger {
  color: #000;
  font-size: 2rem;
}

nav .trigger {
  color: #fff;
}

nav {
  height: 100%;
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 100;
  right: 0;
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: flex-end;
  background: rgba(255, 255, 255, .75);
  transition: transform .3s;
  transform: translateX(100%);
}

nav.show {
  transform: translateX(0%);
}

.nav-inner {
  width: 50%;
  background: blue;
  height: 100%;
}

.open main {
  filter: blur(10px);
}

nav ul {
  margin-top: 50px;
}

nav ul li {
  margin: 20px 0;
}

nav ul a {
  color: #fff;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<nav>
  <div class="nav-inner">
    <a href="" class="trigger">
          close menu
        </a>

    <ul>
      <li>
        <a href="https://ru.stackoverflow.com/" target="_blank">ссылка</a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="https://ru.stackoverflow.com/" target="_blank">ссылка</a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="https://ru.stackoverflow.com/" target="_blank">ссылка</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</nav>

<header>
  <a href="" class="trigger">
      open menu
    </a>
</header>

<main>
  <p>
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Animi voluptatem autem, velit totam, minima quibusdam ea ipsa in saepe eos corporis ipsam dicta, quisquam amet nihil dolores ab officiis ut officia alias accusamus voluptas asperiores dignissimos
    iste ipsum. Nam fugit officia, obcaecati! Quia hic, quasi, modi sequi esse odio deserunt!
  </p>
</main>
```